# How to manage memory when I want to keep some data from an object, but not all?

Tags: c++, oop, memory, memory-management

I'm not experienced in memory management in C++. I have a `Magick::Image` class that holds large images (400MB) and I never need more than one whole image bitmap loaded at a time. I **do** want to have many objects loaded that contain metadata such as resolution, bit-depth and other small info that are related to the images and I want to be able to somehow retrieve the bitmap data (or a pointer to the bitmap data) from a call within those objects.

My solution was to have an `ImageFile` class that holds the metadata and a pointer to the bitmap and also has `load()` and `unload()` methods that allow me to load and unload the bitmap data. Then I can have many objects with the metadata and when I need a bitmap from any of them I can just call `load()` and when I'm done I can just call `unload()`.

Unfortunately, this leads me to a problem: it's possible to pass an ImageFile pointer to a function and access it's bitmap while it's in the unloaded state. In that case I can either (1) throw an exception or (2) I can automatically load the image. Both of these seem bad to me for the following reasons:

1. It seems to me that, philosophically speaking, if you have an instance of some class then that instance should always be in a functional/working state. Having instances that can be in a non-working state seems to require adding additional code and checks and increase program complexity. I might be mistaken here.
2. If I automatically load the image after a method call that requires the bitmap, then when do I unload? The object can't know whether or not the bitmap will be used again soon, so it can't be done automatically (can it?). It seems that manual **un**loading will be required every time, and at that point automatic loading is pointless since we have to do manual work anyways.

For those reasons I am led to believe that my `ImageFile` solution is a bad practice. How do I implement what I need in a more robust way?

Comment: Don't have a pointer to actual bitmap in `ImageFile`. Instead, make `load` a factory function - have it return an object, or a (smart) pointer to an object, representing the bitmap. The caller of `load` is then responsible for destroying it (could be as simple as letting the smart pointer go out of scope). Adding a bit more complexity - `load()` could hand out a `std::shared_ptr` to the bitmap object, and `ImageFile` could keep a `std::weak_ptr` for itself; this way, if the previously loaded bitmap is still alive, `ImageFile` could just hand it out without loading it again.

Comment: "I never need more than one whole image bitmap loaded at a time" - if this is really an invariant of your program, you could have all loading and unloaded done by a single object e.g. `ImageFileManager`, and `ImageFile` objects store only the unique ID for their image file (e.g. the file path) and then consult the `ImageFileManager` to see which image is currently loaded - if it's the wrong one, then unload the previous one and load the new one.

Comment: You might look into implementing an LRU cache of loaded images; that way images that are accessed often stay in memory, and images that are not being accessed get automatically unloaded when the LRU cache reaches its maximum size (which might be very small for your case, i.e. your LRU cache could enforce a maximum only 1 or 2 images in memory at a time)

Comment: Another possibility:  instead of loading in 400MB of data (which is an expensive operation), just `mmap()` the image file into memory (so that it appears to be loaded into memory but in reality each page of on-disk image data will be paged in to RAM only if/when the program actually tries to access it).  That might make "loading" an image file cheap enough that having multiple image files open at once is less of a problem.  (this might work better if your program is 64-bit though, since a 32-bit program might start running low on address space)